# Error running asp.net project in Xamarin.Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin-studio

I tried starting a new asp.net project in Xamarin.Studio, it builds correctly, but when i run it i get this error.

```
"System.UnauthorizedAccessException" 
"Access to the path "/Library/Application Support/com.xamarin.universalinstaller" is denied."
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably made a new installation. Just restart Xamarin Studio then you will be ok.